# Question about tenses used in Seinfeld show: "what you were doing tomorrow night"

Tags: grammar, tenses, backshifting, indirect-speech

In the sentences

> *"Did she even ask you what you **were** doing tomorrow night? If you **were** busy?"*

occurring at about 0:42 - 0:43 in [this clip](http://www.youtube.com/embed/klG_RNMDKIU), why was past tense used in "What you **were** doing tomorrow night", when he was speaking about the future?

Comment: @Chenmunka That is not a conditional. There is no hint of a condition anywhere.

Comment: It is indirect reported speech that is using the backshift preterite (that is, past-tense verbs) for the subordinate clauses that are expressing what had been asked by her. She had asked something like: *"What **are** you doing tomorrow night? **Are** you busy?"*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "Did she even ask you what you **were** doing tomorrow night? If you **were** busy?"

Your example is about indirect reported speech that is using the backshift preterite (that is, a past-tense verb) for the subordinate clauses that are expressing what had been asked by her. She had asked something like:

- *"What **are** you doing tomorrow night? **Are** you busy?"*

Because that kind of info is being reported indirectly by subordinate clauses, their present-tense verbs can, or could, be replaced by backshift preterites. And that is exactly what happened in your original example.

Here are some posts with some more info on the main uses of the preterite, which includes the backshift:

- https://english.stackexchange.com/a/144712/57102
- https://english.stackexchange.com/a/172420/57102

Comment: Are you on strike? Ain't seen no posts for a while ... Don't have any entertainment for when I can get ten minutes off from my work ...

Comment: @Araucaria It does seem to appear to be so. :)

Answer (score 3):

I believe it's in that tense because he is referring what the plans were at that time, not the actual future events that will be occurring tomorrow night.

If your plans change you don't say "We are going to the game next week but it's too expensive so we are watching at home instead."

you say "We *were* going to the game next week but it's too expensive so we are watching at home instead."